# Func<Type> factory. I'm not sure what this is doing in the following example

Tags: c#

I've seen this in some code:

```
class BlahService: ResolverThingy
{
    private IBlahData blahData => this.ResolveDependency<IBlahData>();

    BlahService(Func<IBlahData> blahDataFactory)()
    {
    }
}
```

What is it attempting to do... I'm used to laying my code out like this:

```
class BlahService: ResolverThingy
{
    private IBlahData insightData;

    BlahService(IBlahData blahDataFactory)()
    {
        this.insightData = blahDataFactory
    }
}
```

Is it to delay memory declaration of the `IBlahData` type?

Comment: Isn't it `private Func<IBlahData> blahData => this.ResolveDependency<IBlahData>();` ?

Comment: `private IBlahData blahData => this.ResolveDependency<IBlahData>();` this isn't a valid c# code.

Comment: Its  a delegate. You can get complete info here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just passes delegate to the constructor to resolve the type (implementation) of IBlahData at runtime.

```
class BlahService: ResolverThingy
{
    private Func<IBlahData> blahData => ResolveDependency<IBlahData>();

    public BlahService(Func<IBlahData> blahDataFactory)
    {
       this.blahData = blahDataFactory;
    }

    // usage
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var blahDataImpl = this.blahData();
        // now you can use blahDataImpl
    }
}
```

Comment: So am i right in thinking it's more of a memory saving tool? so that the IBlahData is not resolved until required?

Comment: No, it's called "dependency injection"

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 No I don't think this is saving memory. As @JeffRSon mentioned this is a Dependency Injection, in particular contructor injection. I'm not sure why this style was chosen, instead of injecting implementation, injecting `"Factory method"` which will resolve dependencies for `BlahService`.